# expose deployment on my company's local network ( privet ip )

Tags: kubernetes

I created an app and created for it all the necessary: ​​pods + deployment + service : type loadbalancer with metallb and I created nginxcontroler , ingress and I can get an external ip and I can access it from the same device of mine but I want to make an external ip It works on the rest of the devices on the same network as mine. Can anyone help me?

[image]

I tried to add the ip on /etc/hosts but to no avail

On all my company devices

Is there any help or suggestion for me to try it?

Comment: it should work with the ip 192.168.49.10 (external IP of your service) from other machines in your local network. have you tried that?